# 2010 Subaru Legacy 2.5L CVT - Torque Sequence / Specs for Cylinder Head Bolts

Tags: subaru, cylinder-head, legacy, torque-specification

I can't seem to find the specs for this model year online anywhere.

Comment: Which engine is in your Legacy, the EJ253 or FB25?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've come across quite a few places online that list a torque spec claiming to work for a 2010 Subaru Legacy and/or the EJ25 engine, however these claims are untrue. It seems that a lot of places list torque specs for older models of the Legacy and are claiming that these specs are true for all EJ25/Legacy years.

One big change and probably reason that the torque specs change over years for the legacy is that Subaru's head gaskets were failing on previous year models and they have switched from different gaskets, currently with 2000-2009 using part# 11044AA633 and 2010-2014 using part# 11044AA770 which is a Multi-Layer Steel gasket.

---

Here is the torque spec for the **2010-2014 2.5L SOHC Non-Turbo Legacy** (Turbo and/or DOHC models vary):

```
Bolt Sequence:    
CAF
EBD
```

1. 30 ftlbs
2. 70 ftlbs
3. Loosen 180 degrees, in reverse order
4. Loosen 180 degrees, in reverse order
5. 8 ftlbs
6. 22  ftlbs
7. 44 ftlbs
8. Tighten 90 degrees
9. Tighten 45 degrees
10. Bolts A and B only, tighten 45 degrees

---

Here is the torque spec for the **2005-2009 2.5L Non-Turbo Legacy**:

```
Bolt Sequence:    
CAF
EBD
```

1. 22 ftlbs
2. 51 ftlbs
3. Loosen 180 degrees, in reverse order
4. Loosen 180 degrees, in reverse order
5. 31 ftlbs
6. Tighten 90 degrees
7. Tighten 45 degrees
8. Bolts A and B only, tighten 45 degrees

---

And here is for the 2000-2004 **2.5L Non-Turbo Legacy**:

```
Bolt Sequence:    
CAF
EBD
```

1. 22 ftlbs
2. 51 ftlbs
3. Loosen 180 degrees, in reverse order
4. Loosen 180 degrees, in reverse order
5. Bolts A and B only: 25 ftlbs
6. Bolts C-F only: 11 ftlbs
7. Tighten 90 degrees
8. Tighten 90 degrees

---

So you can see that the torque specs have changed a lot over the years for the Subaru Legacy. It is unfortunate that a lot of sources claim old specs as current, especially as, to my knowledge, an official Subaru Service Manual that would cover this information and be an official Subaru source is unavailable for purchase.

I have even seen the very old 2004 specs being purported as the specs for 2010. Following that would lead to a very different result of middle bolts torqued to 25ftlbs+180deg and outer bolts at 11ftlbs+180deg, while they should be taken to 44ftlbs+180deg for the inner bolts and 44ftlbs+135deg for the outer. It also would skip the 8ftlbs tightening step, which was likely added to the 2010 spec to add extra protection against warping the head during torquing.

Answer (score 1):

The following is from [the FelPro TTY page](https://www.felpro.com/technical/tecblogs/proper-installation-use-t-t-y-bolts.html#:%7E:text=For%20example%20%E2%80%93%20on%20the%20Subaru,45%20degrees%2C%20and%20finally%20the) describing the torque sequence:

[image]

**Note:** While the above image states "E**H**253", to my knowledge Subaru never made an EH253 engine, and above this image on the web page, it spells out for EJ253 in which the sequence matches what's on this image, so I believe the "EH" is a typo and this is actually for your engine.

Comment: I really appreciate all the effort, but unfortunately I believe this torque spec is incorrect for my exact model year. My theory is that this torque spec belongs to the previous model year of Legacy (2004-2009 I believe). Prior to 2010 Subaru had a lot of problems with head gaskets, and I believe they made changes in 2010 to correct them, for one thing changing the material of the gasket to MLS (multi-layer steel). I am trying to compile some sources together to confirm this theory.

Answer (score 0):

The manufacturers factory service manual (FSM) is a good option with diagrams, specs, step by step guides and diagnostics.  You can download the FSM (and other docs) direct from Subaru specifically for your model vehicle via a 72 hour paid pass.  https://techinfo.subaru.com/stis/#/login.